# local or parameter error as it is within scope

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling to understand and fix this error I have where I am trying to grab numbers from a text.

VIrtually I have two pieces of text from `alternativeAirportPrice.Text`. One says:

```
+156 on same day
```

So I want to output only 156 from this text
the other says:

```
-156 on same day
```

So I want to output only - 156 from this text

I implement the `foreach` method to use a `char.IsNumber()`, however I am receiving an error for `c` within `Select(c => c.toString())`

The error is:

> a local or parameter name 'c' cannot be declared in this scope because
>   that name is TestSuite used in an enclosing local scope to define a
>   local or parameter.

What do I need to do to fix this and be able to spit out just the numbers from the text?

```
public string GetAlternativeAirportPrice(By airportPriceLocator)
{
    var alternativeAirportPrices = _driver.FindElements(airportPriceLocator);

    foreach (var alternativeAirportPrice in alternativeAirportPrices)
    {
        if (alternativeAirportPrice.Displayed)
            foreach (char c in alternativeAirportPrice.Text)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(c))
                {
                    alternativeAirportPrice.Text.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
                }
            }
        return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have already declared `c` in your code in the following line:

```
foreach (char c in alternativeAirportPrice.Text)
```

So you can't use it in your `Select` again. Try use something else instead, for example `x`:

```
.Select(x => x.ToString())
```

Or try renaming `c` to something else inside the `foreach`, for example `item`:

```
foreach (char item in alternativeAirportPrice.Text)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(item))
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. One little question. I am not sure if this line of code: alternativeAirportPrice.Text.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray(); is grabbing the number from the text. Seems like it is returning blank. Do you know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @BruceyBandit Yes. In this line `alternativeAirportPrice.Text.ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();` you just select `x` but it is not updating `alternativeAirportPrice.Text`. Probably you should assign this line to some other variable and then return that variable. However you should be aware that this line is returning an array not a string and you should handle this carefully.

Comment: Can you show me how to assigne the variable within the code snippet above as i have quickly tried this but not sure how to return it. I think it's because my method is a string but the variable is a var

Comment: @BruceyBandit Something like this if you want to return string `string t = string.Join("",alternativeAirportPrice.Text.ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());` then return `t`.

Comment: @BruceyBandit Your main issue is resolved that question was about that. Answering the further questions in comments are hard. I'd suggest that you ask a new question about your new problem with more details.

Comment: That's cool, thanks again for your help :). I actually resolve the select thing by retyping it which was weird. I will figure out the return t part. Thansk